# Import one model inside urls.py from other app

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to import model from another app inside urls.py from different app.

This is my code

**main/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'clients',
    'rest_framework',
)
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import routers

from myapp.clients.models import Client

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'clients', ClientViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

**clients/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    number_of_requests = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    karma = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    member_from = models.DateTimeField('member from')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

I am getting error No module named 'myapp.clients'

main/urls.py in , line 25

That is this line: **from myapp.clients.models import Client**

Can somebody advice how can I fix this? I am new to python, and struggling with this issue for few hours. Thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing all of that in urls.py. it's for, well, URLs only.

Comment: yes, I know. Thanks for suggestion. I will move everything in different files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clients` is an installed app, so you should be able to change that line to:

```
from clients.models import Client
```

Comment: It appears that the directory is actually called 'client'. It might need to be 'from client.models import Client', and the app name in installed apps might need to be updated to client.

Comment: @ChidGilovitz I believe that's a typo, based on the use of `clients` elsewhere (such as the DRF router).

Comment: @ChidGilovitz client was a typo, sorry about that. Now it is fixed. This solution solved my problem, thanks a lot! I just can't understand why PyCharm marks that line as incorrect - but it works in the browser.